# How can I use a word that contains a special character(ü) in a .dic file?(Python)

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding, special-characters

I'm trying to classify texts with a translated LIWC Dictionary. But the library I'm using($pip install liwc) is not able to parse words that contains special Turkish characters for example "ü".

Here is the .dic file I'm using for test purposes.

```
%
4   sad
19  health
%
terketmek   4
kürtaj  19
```

So when I try to parse this sentence "kabul terketmek naber yawru a asit kürtaj yapabilmek." it does not classify the word "kürtaj" because it contains "ü".

I tried to solve it by myself and I only could find that the library I'm using parses the word "kürtaj" like this "kÃ¼rtaj" when it is reading the lines from the .dic file I provided.

So, probably that's why the library doesn't classify the word "kürtaj" because it gets lost in translation :)

Thanks in advance!

[Python liwc package.](https://pypi.org/project/liwc/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried adding `encoding='utf8'` as a parameter to the `open` function where it reads the file and it worked.